# Changing language option

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following code in my settings.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr'


LANGUAGES = (
   ('nl', 'Dutch'),
   ('fr', 'French'),
   ('en-us', 'English'),  
)
```

Middleware_classes

```
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
```

When I print "LANGUAGE_CODE" in the terminal I always get "en-us" though I set it as "fr". But if I remove "en-us" from Languages it shows "fr".

What mistake Im doing here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you printing it from `manage.py shell` or from `runserver`? In first case you should get `fr` but in second actual language code will be [discovered](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference) by `LocaleMiddleware`